# Помогите с настройкой urls.py Django

Tags: python, django

Сделал новый проект на джанге, да вот беда - что-то глючат урлы, не могу понять где ошибка. Вроде делал всё как обычно, ьно страница не отображается, вместо неё 404 джанги.

project urls.py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from django.conf.urls import include, url, patterns
from django.contrib import admin
import djdb_queue.urls
from django.views.generic import RedirectView

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Examples:
    # url(r'^$', 'djdb_queue_project.views.home', name='home'),
    # url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls')),

    #url(r'^$', RedirectView.as_view(url='/djdb_queue/')),
    url(r'^/djdb_queue/', include('djdb_queue.urls',namespace="djdb_queue")),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)


from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = urlpatterns  + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT) + \
              static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

application urls.py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from django.conf.urls import include, url, patterns
from django.contrib import admin
from djdb_queue.views import *

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Examples:
    # url(r'^$', 'djdb_queue_project.views.home', name='home'),
    # url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls')),

    url(r'^test/$', TestPageView.as_view(), name='main'),
    #url(r'^$', TestPageView.as_view(), name='testpageview'),

    )
```

Comment: Во-первых, какая страница? Во-вторых, какая версия Django?

Comment: Уже всё заработало, не надо писать лидирующий слэш оказывается - сним не работает

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Уже всё заработало, не надо писать лидирующий слэш оказывается - с ним не работает.

```
 url(r'^/djdb_queue/'
```

так не работает

```
url(r'^djdb_queue/'
```

так работает